# To store a large string 1000 charecter in DB2 stored procedure

Tags: database, stored-procedures, db2

I have declare a variable of `varchar(1000)` in a DB2 stored procedure. But when I am trying to store a text of 500 characters, it's getting truncated to 262 characters only.

Please help me how I can store this large text in any other datatype or in `varchar` itself.

Comment: `VARCHAR(1000)` can store 1000 bytes; each UTF-8 character can take up to 4 bytes, and each UTF-16 character takes exactly 4 bytes. Watch your character encoding.

Comment: if mustachioed suggestion doesn't solve your problem, show us your code

Comment: I am simply testing with a group of alphabets like
'abcdefgechi..........' as a sequence of 1000 charecters but stil the variable is giving me only 262 strating charecters..where I am missing any thing

Comment: Show your DDL (the `create table` statement showing the detail of the column where you want to store the data), then __show your code__   for the insert, otherwise this question will get closed for lack of debugging details.  Most likely you are making false assumptions, learn how to check your assumptions.